# Custom Zend Error message for checkboxes

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I have a form in a Zend-based site which has a required "Terms and Conditions" checkbox.

I have set a custom message which says "you must agree with terms and conditions".

however, because the checkbox is "presence='required'", it returns

```
Field 'terms' is required by rule 'terms', but the field is missing
```

which is this constant defined in the Zend framework:

```
self::MISSING_MESSAGE     => "Field '%field%' is required by rule '%rule%', but the field is missing",
```

I could edit this constant, but this would change the error reporting for all required checkboxes.

How can I affect the error reporting for this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default message like this:

```
$options = array(
                'missingMessage' => "Field '%field%' is required by rule '%rule%', dawg!"
            );
```

And then:

```
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $myData);
```

**Or**

```
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $myData);
$input->setOptions($options);
```

...and finally:

```
if ($input->hasInvalid() || $input->hasMissing()) {
  $messages = $input->getMessages();
}
```

It's mentioned on the `Zend_Filter_Input` [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) page.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the `Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox` you can [customize the error messages on the `Zend_Validate` validators](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html#zend.validate.introduction.messages).

```
$form->addElement('checkbox', 'terms', array(
  'label'=>'Terms and Services',
  'uncheckedValue'=> '',
  'checkedValue' => 'I Agree',
  'validators' => array(
    // array($validator, $breakOnChainFailure, $options)
    array('notEmpty', true, array(
      'messages' => array(
        'isEmpty'=>'You must agree to the terms'
      )
    ))
   ),
   'required'=>true,
);
```

You want to make sure the unchecked value is "blank" and that the field is "required"

Answer (score 1):

Following @gnarf answer, for those of you who may set Form Fields in a slightly different way (like me), you could also do the following:

```
$agree_tc_and_privacy = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('agree_tc_and_privacy');
$agree_tc_and_privacy
->setLabel("My T&Cs Agreement text ...")
->addValidator('NotEmpty', false, array('messages' => 'You must and agree...'))
->setRequired(true)
->setOptions(
    array(
        'uncheckedValue'=> '', //important as explained by gnarf above
        'checkedValue' => '1',
    )
);
$this->addElement($agree_tc_and_privacy);
```